# How to improve PHP code against SQL injection and other threats

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

How can I modify this code to improve protection against sql injection and other threats? It is a MS SQL database.

```
<?php include_once("db.php"); ?>

<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
settype($id, 'string');

$tsql = "SELECT Table1.Fund FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Fund='%s'";
$tsqlnew=sprintf($tsql, $id);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsqlnew);
if( $stmt === false)
{
echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$chd = '';

while( $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  {
$chd .= '[\''.$data['Fund'] .'\'],';
}
$chd = substr($chd,0,-1);

?>
```

I'm also wondering if my db connection can be improved.  Thanks for your help!

```
<?php

$myServer = "server";
$myUser = "userPlaceHolder";
$myPass = "passwordPlaceHolder";
$myDB = "SQL";

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, array('UID'=>$myUser, 'PWD'=>$myPass, 'Database'=>$myDB));

if( $conn === false )
{
echo "Could not connect.\n";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: suppose your $_REQUEST['id'] is coming from an input field. Use mysql_real_escape_string function to scape special characters from the string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: Honestly? Change the whole code! In my opinion, it's much better to read about http://php.net/PDO and http://php.net/Filter even you will have to use php 5 as Marc B already suggested. Your code looks like in the 90s and I'm pretty sure few hours of reading about php coding practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code does exactly **NOTHING** to prevent injection attacks. Merely forcing variable to have a string-data type is exactly as much protection as a piece of toilet paper provides against a tsunami.

To prevent injection attacks, you must escape all data that you insert into a query string, whether it's user-provided or something you yourself have created/inserted.

Best option is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php), which relieves you of the responsibility of escaping data.

Even if the data being inserted isn't "malicious", any SQL metacharacters (quotes in particular) can still destroy the query and cause syntax errors.

Comment: If the overall mass of the toilet paper has more stored energy than the tsunami, toilet paper actually wins ;)

Comment: @Hakre: I wouldn't want to see the rear end that would require such a large piece... "that's no moon..."

Comment: Thanks, the link is very helpful.  I originally used the settype() coding as suggested in this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) but it obviously isn't a good solution and would work better if the input were numerical.